# Error parsing Regex Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regex-negation

I want a regex expression in C# to allow everything but these special characters: `*~!@#$%^()|\?/<>=+_`

So I've created the following expression:   `^[^\*~!@#\$%\^()|\\?/<>=+_]+$`

However, when I use the Regex.IsMatch method to verify user input with the regex pattern I get an error stating:

> System.ArgumentException: parsing "*~!@#$%^()|\?/<>=+_" - Quantifier
>   {x,y} following nothing.

After a search in google I found out that my expression is not escaped properly - **but it is escaped**. Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: @AlonMass: Please post the whole relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `@` to make a verbatim string

```
string myRegex =  @"^[^\*~!@#\$%\^()|\\?\/<>=+_]+$";
```

Thanks to [stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) here's where the issue is:

```
string myRegex = "^[^\*~!@#\$%\^()|\\?/<>=+_]+$";
                     ^     ^  ^
```

In fact, the errors you get [with this code](http://ideone.com/c3XQ3D) are:

```
prog.cs(7,24): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\*'
prog.cs(7,30): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\$'
prog.cs(7,33): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\^'
```

Your regex should look like:

```
var rx = @"^[^*~!@#$%^()|\\?/<>=+_]+$";
```

Comment: If it is the right answer, OP posted a wrong error. The error that is thrown when using a regular string literal is `error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence \*'`, etc.

Comment: @stribizhev corrected (I think)

Comment: Why escape `/` in C# regex? The right regex declaration here will look like `string myRegex =  @"^[^*~!@#$%^()|\\?/<>=+_]+$";`.

Comment: @stribizhev because Regex101 [told me to do so](https://regex101.com/r/lE7nL2/1) ?

Comment: You cannot use regex101 to test .NET regexps, it does not support their syntax. And you should test the regexes in the online IDEs to check if they are valid.Although why bother, people upvote anything today, and downvote correct answers. Here is [a demo of what should work](https://ideone.com/YN1fvi).

Comment: @stribizhev Do you have a magic address ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95581/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-thomas).

Comment: I used the above regex, Thank you @Thomas. However, lets say that I want to test the input: "<test" I get an error stating:

System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Model.Property="<test").

Comment: @AlonMass that's for another question :)

Comment: Ohhh common..... :)
I can't post question.....

Comment: @AlonMass you'll be able in 36 min